# What is the best method for determining "side of street" when navigation complete in Skobbler?

Tags: android, ios, skmaps

I've been searching for any documentation that may provide this already but have been unable to do so. I was wondering for both the iOS and Android versions of the Skobbler SDK, is there a way to return information regarding what side of the street a destination will be at?

We notice that the Skobbler audio advice returns the correct side of the street but weren't sure if there was a method to get that information programmatically so we can update our UI to show the corresponding information. One work around we have in place is parsing the text spoken by the audio advice to see if it contains "destination on left" or "destination on right" but that doesn't seem like the most robust solution moving forward.

Thanks for any help in the matter!
Keith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now there is no particular flag indicating the "side" of the street for the destination (that is accessible programmatically).

Parsing the text instruction for the "side" flag value would be the way to go. See [this](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/advisor-support-text-to-speech-scout-audio/) blog post for more details regarding how the text/audio advices are composed

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ando. Let me know if there is a way to request this to be a feature in a future SDK release somehow or if this post in itself serves that purpose. Thanks again for the quick reply.